# What's the equivalent of the apport-retrace (Ubuntu) command for Debian?

Tags: logs, freeze, error-handling

I have some freezing troubles I cannot find the cause for a long time on my *Debian* VM,
and I'm interested in using a command `apport-retrace` that a *Linux* magazine I've bought promotes to do some analysis.

It exists on *Ubuntu* but I didn't found it on *Debian* who marks it experimental or removed, I don't remember, in the web pages showing package lists.

What's the equivalent of `apport-retrace` I should use, on a *Debian* distribution, to have some tools going into logs and traces to find remarkable things?